# SSLPeerUnverifiedException while downloading file from github using Gradle task

Tags: github, gradle

I need to get a file from github using gradle. I found [this plugin](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task). The following example works for me:

```
task downloadZipFile(type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/archive/1.0.zip'
    dest new File(buildDir, '1.0.zip')
}
```

But when i replace URL with the one i need: (https://github.com/broadinstitute/cromwell/releases/download/0.19/cromwell-0.19.jar) i get the following error:

```
8:00:37 AM: Executing external task 'downloadZipFile'...
:downloadZipFile
Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: logged_in=no; domain=.github.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 13 Jun 2036 12:00:38 -0000; secure; HttpOnly". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Fri, 13 Jun 2036 12:00:38 -0000
:downloadZipFileFAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':downloadZipFile'.
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.91 secs
Host name 'github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
8:00:39 AM: External task execution finished 'downloadZipFile'.
```

What can be wrong, i just replace github URL with another github URL.

Comment: `acceptAnyCertificate true` helped me a bit, but it does not seem to be secure solution :\

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @RaGe nope. Notice that original task with https github link works without problems

Comment: if you put the cromwell url in a browser address bar, it redirects to a more complex s3 url. Maybe you should use that url instead?

Comment: This is the s3 url btw, not sure if it is dynamically generated and thus short-lived: https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/34136406/2db236aa-f823-11e5-9869-5a08ce6f1c6d.jar?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ%2F20160613%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160613T132613Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=fcfa23e35f4011052cebeef70a8a5a29d220e49d86d832c5e44b3515b45352f3&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=8560257&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dcromwell-0.19.jar&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream

Comment: gradle-download-task 3.1.2 has just been released. It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/issues/56#issuecomment-236349889), add the following to the beginning of your `build.gradle` script:

```
// Temporary workaround, see
// https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/issues/56
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.1.1'
        classpath 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
    }
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: The workaround should not be necessary anymore. gradle-download-task 3.1.2 has just been released.